# Find a class using js and localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to convert a value stored by localStorage and then turn it into a class so I can manipulate it in the DOM.

I'm very new to javascript, so please allow me to explain:

I have a html file with multiple divs, and localStorage stores the class of the div that was last clicked.

I want my script to call the stored class from localStorage, find the div with that class (using jquery OR js, doesn't matter) and then change the background colour of that div using .css(), for example. I'll be able to do what I need to do with that logic, but I can't get it to work.

So what I am trying to do is $('the last clicked div').css({..manipulate the css..});

Is this possible?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //always show the current div class
        $("b").html(localStorage.getItem("currentDiv"));


        //get the class of the div that's just been clicked
        $("div").click(function(){
            var currentClass = $(this).attr("class");
            localStorage.setItem("currentDiv", currentClass);
            $("b").html(localStorage.getItem("currentDiv"));
        });


        //show the div that was last clicked
        function currentStatus(){
            if (localStorage.getItem("currentDiv") === $(currentClass))
            {
                $(currentClass).show();
                $("b").html(localStorage.getItem("currentDiv"));
            }
        }

        //set a color for the recently clicked div dynamically, not by .click
        var highlightClass = localStorage.getItem("currentDiv");
        highlightClass.css({
            'background' : 'black'
        })

    });

    $('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
        localStorage.clear();
    });


    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    [class*="slide"]{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 40px;
    background: #999;
    margin: 20px;
    }
    /*.slide1{
    display: block;
    }*/
    </style>

    </head>

    <body onLoad="currentStatus()">
        <div class="slide1">
            <h1>"A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide2">
            <h1>"A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide3">
            <h1>"A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide4">
            <h1>"A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide5">
            <h1>"A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide6">
            <h1>"A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide7">
            <h1>"A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <b></b>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The currentStatus function is assigned to the body's onload function, but is defined until the jquery ready event. I'm not completely sure what order these events are called, but that's what my first instinct would be to check.

Comment: You don't include jQuery anywhere.

Comment: I did on my version @MarcelKorpel - but when I posted my message here strange things happened so I stripped it out.

Comment: Sorry @user4815162342 I don't understand what you mean? What should I check?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to put your script at the bottom of your `body` element. Moreover, get rid of that `onload` handler and just call `currentStatus` at the bottom of your document.ready function. Then it will show the class name of the last clicked item.

Comment: Thanks, I do know about keeping the script at the bottom, was just being lazy ;) - I had actually moved it to the bottom since posting here.

Comment: I've fixed this now, I was being an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to make it work, the core thing being: $("."+currentDivClass) which converts the string to a class!

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    [class*="slide"]{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 40px;
    background: #999;
    margin: 20px;
    }
    /*.slide1{
    display: block;
    }*/
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="slide1">
            <h1>"1 A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide2">
            <h1>"2 A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide3">
            <h1>"3 A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide4">
            <h1>"4 A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide5">
            <h1>"5 A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide6">
            <h1>"6 A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slide7">
            <h1>"7 A question would go here."</h1>
        </div>
        <b></b>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //always show the current div class
        $("b").html(localStorage.getItem("currentDiv"));


        //get the class of the div that's just been clicked
        $("div").click(function(){
            var currentClass = $(this).attr("class");
            localStorage.setItem("currentDiv", currentClass);
            $("b").html(localStorage.getItem("currentDiv"));
        });


        //convert the string of the last clicked div into a class and then work your magic
        var currentDivClass = localStorage.getItem("currentDiv");
        $("."+currentDivClass).css({
            'background' : 'red'
        });


    });

    $('#localStorageTest').submit(function() {
        localStorage.clear();
    });


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```